# log scale in c from 1 until 100000000

Tags: c

how can i create log scale in c like 1,2,3..10,20,30,..,100,200..1000,...100000000 since the control increment in loop only using ++i (multiplied by 10,100,...etc)?

i tried loop in the loop and it's not working

````
void main()
{
   long j,i,n;
   printf("Input upto the table number starting from 1 : ");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   printf("Multiplication from 1 to %d \n",n);

for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
   {
     for(j=1;j<=10;++j)
     {

       if (i<11){
            printf("%ld x %ld = %ld, ",i,j,j*i);
        }
        else if(i>10){
            printf("10 x %ld = %ld, \n",j,j*10);
        } 
        else if(i>100){
            printf("100 x %ld = %ld, \n",j,j*100);
        }
        else if(i>1000){
            printf("1000 x %ld = %ld,\n",j,j*1000);
        }
        else if(i>10000){
            printf("10000x%ld = %ld, ",i,j*10000);
        }

        printf("\n");
      }
   
    }
} ```
````

Comment: can you give an example of input and expected output?

Comment: well i wanna generate frequency which is from 1 to 400 MHz, of course it will takes so much times if its done one by one, so i want to generate let's say input: start frequency 1 Hz, stop frequency 400 MHz.
                output
1 - 10 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
10-100 =10,20,30,40,50...100
100-1000 = 100,200,300,400,500,...1000 and so on until 100000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long i,j;
    long n;
    scanf("%ld",&n);
    for(i=1;;i*=10)
    {
        for(j=1;j<10;j++)
        {
            if(i*j <= n) {
                printf("mult=%ld\n", i*j);
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `j<=10` should probably be `j<10`, otherwise I have a feeling there would be multiple exponents of 10 in the output. `if (i*j <= n)` is also not necessary if you use `for (i=1; i<n; i*=10)`.

Comment: @Groo took your first note, the second note would cause the loop to go more than needed